# Spring IoC - constructing context dependent beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Consider the following code:

```
@Service
class UserSpecificService {
    @Autowired ServiceA serviceA;
    @Autowired ServiceB serviceB;
    @Autowired User user;

    public void doUserSpecificThings() {
        // consume serviceA, serviceB and user here
    }
}

@Service class ServiceA {}
@Service class ServiceB {}

@Service
class Facade {
    public void doThingsForUser(Long userId) {
        User user = userService.getById(userId);
        UserSpecificService userSpecificService = ...; // !!!
        userSpecificService.doUserSpecificThings();
    } 
}
```

The question is about line marked with `// !!!`. Is there any way I can construct `UserSpecificService` *without* implementing my own factory which is aware of `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, and only requires an instance of `User` to instantiate a `UserSpecificService`?

If it matters - I'm going to use the `Facade` with Spring MVC, though I'd like it not to rely on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should give FactoryBeans a try http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/10/beyond-the-factorybean/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

- make all services that are eligible to be `userSpecificService` (I guess these are ServiceA and serviceB) have a common interface
- let that interface have two methods - `doUserSpecificThing()` and `isEligibleFor(user)`
- use `@Autowired List<YourInterface> list`
- in your `doThingsForUser()` method iterate the list of all instances of the given interface, and for each of them check if it is eligible for the given user. If it is - invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can create a UserSpecificService dynamically without having to maunally set the services, try this:

```
@Configurable
class UserSpecificService {
    @Autowired private ServiceA serviceA;
    @Autowired private ServiceB serviceB;
    private User user;

    public UserSpecificService(User user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void doUserSpecificThings() {
        // consume serviceA, serviceB and user here
    }
}

@Service class ServiceA {}
@Service class ServiceB {}

@Service
class Facade {
    public void doThingsForUser(Long userId) {
        User user = userService.getById(userId);
        UserSpecificService userSpecificService = new UserSpecificService(user);
        userSpecificService.doUserSpecificThings();
    } 
}
```

Just be aware that you will need to configre your spring context to scan for @Configurable. To do this all you have to do is add `<context:spring-configured/>` to your application context file.  Another approach would be:

```
@Service
class UserSpecificService {
    @Autowired private ServiceA serviceA;
    @Autowired private ServiceB serviceB;

    public void doUserSpecificThings(User user) {
        // consume serviceA, serviceB and user here
    }
}

@Service class ServiceA {}
@Service class ServiceB {}

@Service
class Facade {
    public void doThingsForUser(Long userId) {
        User user = userService.getById(userId);
        userSpecificService.doUserSpecificThings(user);
    } 
}
```

That approach may be better depending on your specific application.